# Python, How to find length of the dimensions of array with 3 dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of bool like this, and I want to reach the length of its first and second dimensions. How do I do that:

[image]

[image]

So I want to get the sizes of these dimensions like:

```
Size_Of_First_Dimension(mask_points) 
--> 480
```

Comment: What is `type(mask_points)`?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Does `mask_points` have a `shape` attribute?

Comment: type(mask_points) --> numpy.ndarray

Comment: mask_points.shape --> 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: "shape" isn't a function, don't call it.

Comment: my bad, mask_points.shape --> (812, 1200, 1)

Comment: mask_points.shape[0] works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a numpy array, then `mask_points.shape` is a tuple of the sizes of the dimensions (in this case, the 0th and the 1st).